# How can I find in Excel the last column where the value is different than in the prior column?

Tags: excel

[image: Find the last column where a change happened]

I have many rows with measurements that progress from left to right with the rightmost measurement being the most recent one. Often the values become zero at some point and stay zero until the end.

I am trying to find the last column where a change happened. I tried a lot but could not figure it out. In the first example (row 2) this would be column V (=column with the heading 18) where the value is -1.60 and no further values are available. In the second example (row 3) this would be column P (heading 12) and so on. In order to find this last-change column I have three steps (columns A, B, C) and a check (column D) to see if there are indeed no more non-zero values afterwards. This works well in many cases but it does not work if there is a zero value and then non-zero values before it is all zero to the end (rows 6 and 7). As there are in my case many columns (up to 270) it should be a general formula.

I would love to attach the sample Excel but I think this is not possible here. I did however paste the data part (E1:W7) as a csv here [example data as csv](https://pastebin.com/raw/7NyrA5sZ), hope that is ok. Here the four formulas for row 7 and columns A to D:

```
=COUNT(E7:W7)
=INDEX($E7:$W7,0,$A7)
=MATCH($B7,$E7:$W7,0)
=SUM(INDEX($E7:$W7,0,$C7+1):W7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the *position* (or corresponding column header) of the last value that has changed, you can use Aggregate:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,D$1:U$1/((D2:U2<>"")*(C2:T2<>D2:U2)),1)
```

or if you have Excel 365, you can use Filter:

```
=MAX(FILTER(D$1:U$1,(D2:U2<>"")*(D2:U2<>C2:T2)))
```

Then you can use Index to find the value as before:

```
=INDEX(C2:T2,A2)
```

or use @Ron Rosenfield's formula.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`=LOOKUP(2,1/((B4:Z4<>C4:AA4)*NOT(ISBLANK(C4:AA4))),C4:AA4)`

This formula should return the last change, if I've understood the logic of what you are doing.

If not giving expected results, post back with an example of the failed row and what you expect.

Note that two horizontal references are used, with one being offset from the other by one column.

[image]